# play embedded video in android web view

Tags: android, titanium, android-webview, appcelerator

I want to play video in android web view. I am using embedded HTML code to open it in android web view. My device has flash player installed in it. when I play the video then I am getting sound of video but there is no picture or video displaying. please help to run embedded video in android web view. I have set hardware acceleration also. please help me.

Comment: are you testing on a real device or emulator ?

Comment: yes I am testing in device but facing same problem.

Comment: What you have tried please post here to get appropriate answers.

Comment: I want to open this url in web view [http://play.streamingvideoprovider.com/popplayer.php?it=463122](http://play.streamingvideoprovider.com/popplayer.php?it=463122). and I am able to play this url in browser but unable to play video in web view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open the URL in browser.. Embedded videos are not playing in web view this is open bug in appcelerator titanium here is the link...
https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-4801